# Printing the bibliography twice?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am preparing a paper submission to a conference that wants two PDFs:

- A main paper
- A supplementary material section (e.g. appendices at the end)

And, I intend to release a preprint that has the main paper and appendicies in one PDF.

So, what I would like to do is to have one numbered reference list (generated by bibtex) that is shared across both PDFs. And, for the use-case of submitting to the conference that wants two PDFs, I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
...
\section{Conclusion}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieee}

% ---- begin supplementary material ----

\section*{Appendix A}

% print the bibliography again
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieee}

\end{document}
```

When I do the above, it complains that `Label '2018_authorname' multiply defined.` (2018_authorname is the name of an item in the bibliography file that I supply to bibtex.)

So, one solution I am trying to figure out is: can I somehow print the bibliography as a string to a variable (like you would in a normal computer program), and then print that string in two different places in the document?

Or, are there other ways that people have dealt with this?

Comment: Replace the second invocation of `\bibliography{bibliography}` by `\InputIfFileExists{bibliography.bbl}{}{}`.

Answer (score 2):

I learned that it is straightforward to print the bibliography multiple times if I use `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`. That's because biblatex provides the `\printbibliography` command, which can be called multiple times.

Here's what I came up with:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
...
\section{Conclusion}

\printbibliography

% ---- begin supplementary material ----

\section*{Appendix A}

% print the bibliography again
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I added the ieee.bbx and ieee.cbx files from [this package](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee?lang=en) to my working directory, and that enabled biblatex to use `style=ieee` in the above.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question using `\bibliography`, here is how you make a duplicate

```
% print the bibliography again
\begin{@fileswfalse}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{@fileswfalse}
```

If you make a TOC entry, put it before the `\begin`.

Comment: Confirming, this works.