# Printing two bibliographies using revtex4 template

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I'm writing a paper using the revtex4 to be submitted to the arxiv. It is for the Physical Review Letters journal. I want to include a bibliography section at the end of the main text, and another bibliography at the end of the supplementary information section. The suggestions in [Printing the bibliography twice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546182/printing-the-bibliography-twice) are not helpful.

My MWE gives me errors saying there are package incompatibilities between biblatex and natbib (which is what I assume that revtex4 uses). Any suggestions would be great.

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn,floatfix,showpacs,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{blindtext,lipsum}
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\title{my paper title}

\author{author 1}
\address{university 1}

\author{author 2}%
\address{university 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
abstract of my paper
\end{abstract}

%\pacs{}

\maketitle

%% start main
\paragraph*{Introduction} -- This is my paper \cite{paper2007} \cite{paper2012}.

\lipsum[1-1]
\lipsum[2-4]

\paragraph*{References}

\printbibliography


\clearpage
\textbf{\large Supplementary Material}

%%%%%%%%%% Prefix a "S" to all equations, figures, tables and reset the counter %%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[S#1]}
\renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{S#1}

This Supplementary Material presents technical details \cite{paper2007} \cite{paper2010}...

\blindtext

\paragraph*{References}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt you will be able to use `biblatex` in a submission to a journal that wants you to use RevTeX. RevTeX loads `natbib` and `natbib` and `biblatex` are completely incompatible. (But even if you could stop the class from loading `natbib`, I'd be very sceptical that the publisher would be happy to accept `biblatex`, it requires a *very* different workflow: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)

Comment: Ok, I don't mind not using biblatex etc though. I just need some way to print the bibliography twice.